# Unable to open RAR file using WinZip program

Tags: rar

I have .rar file downloaded and when i try to open using the winzip program in my local laptop, it throws an alert "Can not open the "xxx.rar file. It appears to be Invalid archive". But if i rename it to zip then it opens just fine.

Also i can use the winrar program to open the rar file, but i would like to open the rar file using winzip program. Is there a way to make it possible?

Comment: Are you sure this is actually a RAR file? Is it actually compressed at all? RAR and ZIP are two different things that happen to accomplish similar goals. You shouldn't be able to just rename a RAR to a ZIP and get it to open unless the file is actually a ZIP or unless there is no actual compression on the file.

Comment: it's fairly normal that sometimes a program can have an issue.. the normal thing is to try other programs.. people tend to use 7-zip

Answer (score -1):

In WinZip:

Go to settings 
WinZip options 
dropdown menu click WinZip options
Integration
Archives - Associations...add a tick mark to extensions you want WinZip to handle and untick the ones you do not want associated with WinZip.
Now you are ready to just double click the rar file and unzip it from Explorer or within WZ.

Comment: This is not an answer to the actual problem. Your solution is about setting the default file handler for these extensions. The question is about getting WinZip to recognize a specific file type at all.